# Securely store application secrets in production without 3rd party KMS

Tags: appsec, key-management, sql-server, secrets-management

1. Integrated Security

I have a ASP.NET web application with connection strings and other secrets to protect in production. Ideally I would like to use IntegratedSecurity to keep SQL credentials out of the connection strings, but IIS Express uses my personal logged in windows account to authenticate with IntegratedSecurity, and apparently IIS Express is impossible to be configured to use any other windows identity.

Using Local IIS running under an AppPool with identical permissions as on prod instead of IIS Express might be an option but I get a 500 error trying to launch the app from IIS Manager, and have had trouble making it work, but even if I did, configuring the rest of the team's IIS the same way could be a pain and even worse, debugging mode won't work, breakpoints will not be hit launching the app this way. Plus this doesn't address my API keys etc that also need to be protected.

2. Key Management System

So it seems like I need to use another option. Azure Key Vault is a common solution I see but I don't see how it improves security considering you still need to supply credentials to Azure Key Vault, and those creds must be stored somewhere the application can access them, kicking the same problem down the road. I know Azure Key Vault can use certificates for authentication but is that any more secure than the client secret way enough to justify adding more complexity of dealing with rotating certificates? I'm new to security but I imagine this is a well known phenomenon. Furthermore my supervisors explicitly don't want to use 3rd party solutions.

I looked into using a token-based authentication system like [OpenIddict](https://documentation.openiddict.com/guides/index.html) for accessing an Encryption API to encrypt or decrypt secrets, but there's the same problem of storing client id and client secret in the source code, it adds complexity, and if that Encrpytion API went down for any reason, multiple apps would cease to work. I'm not fond of this solution.

3. Environment variables

It seems the concensus on storing secrets in environment variables is that it is not secure, unless they are encrypted, in which case the private key to decrypt them must be accessible to the application. Same problem again.

I think I've outlined my problem thoroughly and described my options and why they don't work for my use case. This data is very sensitive and so the highest feasible level of security would be ideal. What options do I have left?

Comment: The question is opinion based. I suggest to close it.